# C# / Visual Studio - Team Explorer Extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a new Visual Studio extension and I've finished everything apart from one small problem. I've tried searching around for it. However all I've found is old documents and articles that are no longer working. Neither does Microsoft have any documentation on this subject.

I need the active Git Repo that visual studio is currently using when you have selected it. So when I press my button it gets the active repo and executes.

I was looking into "Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client" but I can't seem to find a way to get the url/active repo from there. So I assume is not that I have to use.

((The picture is GitHub, however the button have to function mainly in TFS, but I assume thats the same code))

[image: Picture of help required]

Comment: Have a look at how the GitHub extension works: https://github.com/github/VisualStudio There's probably what you need in there.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I mainly need it to work for Git when using TFS. However I will take a look in the code and see if their might be a solution in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same issue as you the last couple of days at work. After Steven Kirk from GitHub Introduced the "IGitExt" to me yesterday, I managed to solve it.

```
var gitExt = ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(IGitExt)) as IGitExt;
```

By using the "gitExt" you can reach all the information required to solve your issue.

IGitExt interface sadly seems to be undocumented, so I do understand why you’re having issue solving this task.

You can find information about the Service Provider here:: [Link to Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.package.getglobalservice?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)

You can find the dll to the IGitExt on your local computer: `Path to VS\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.dll`

You can only use this from Visual Studio 2013 and above.

Feel free to comment if you need additional help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to retrieve the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.Git.Extensibility.IGitExt object (introduced in Visual Studio 2013 Update 3) via GetService.  It exposes the active Git repository, the repo local path, the current branch, and the head SHA for that branch.  Additional info about the repo can then be queried using LibGit2Sharp.  The interface lives in the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider assembly.

This should have been documented publicly along with the rest of the Team Explorer extensibility, but it seems to have been missed.